# Subtle WM without a numpad

Tags: tiling-wm, netbook

I just started using subtle WM on a netbook, and there are keybindings that need a numpad. I'm still not familiar with the terminology, but I think it's for the gravities. Is there a way to configure subtle for a netbook/laptop so it doesn't require a numpad?

Answer (score 1):

- [From its Wiki:](http://subforge.org/projects/1/wiki/Subtle/)

> `subtle` is a manual tiling window manager with a rather uncommon approach of tiling: Instead of relying on predefined layouts, `subtle` **divides the screen into a grid with customizable slots (called gravities)**. For better understanding, the default config uses a **3x3 grid and maps each gravity to one key of the numpad**. With those keys, windows can be moved directly to the desired gravity - the same can be done with tagging rules in the config.

- [There's also an example page](http://subforge.org/projects/subtle/wiki/Gravity#Examples) illustrating the concept a little, explaining how gravities are configured.
- Also see the FAQ item [*"How can I use subtle without numpad?"*](http://subforge.org/ezfaq/show/subtle?faq_id=16), suggesting how to change the keybindings in a suitable way.